# How to initialize a pointer pointing to an array to null values for all index in the array

Tags: c++, c++17

```
 T *newPtr = nullptr;
 T array[size] = {};
 newPtr = array;
```

I am trying to have a pointer point to an array of a custom size. My code above works but it starts giving me lvalue errors when I initialize to {}. I want to initialize all the indices in the array to nullptr, but I am having trouble understanding how this would work if its even possible. What is the best way to initialize and check if the values in the array are empty using a pointer?

Comment: C tag removed. Please note that C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: `check if the values in the array are empty` That depends on what `T` is and what you mean by "*empty*". See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: is it possible to check if the array has been assigned a value regardless of the type? Thats what I was trying to say by empty. I just was wondering how you could check if your index has not been assigned a value.

Comment: Every element of an array has a value. That value may be *indeterminate*  if it hasn't been explicitly initialized, in which case reading it invokes *undefined behavior*. There is no such things as an array element without a value

Comment: If `size` isn't a compile-time constant, with `T array[size];` you are declaring a Variable Lenght Array, which is not part of C++ standard (it requires a C99 compliant compiler). Even in C, those can't be initialized with `= {}`. Try `std::vector<T> a(size);`, instead, and then declare an `auto ptr = &a;` if you *really* need a pointer to it.

Comment: @Bob__ that would probably be `auto ptr = a.data();`.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, probably. The OP does state *"I am trying to have a pointer point to an array of a custom size"*, but they likely mean what you mention.

Answer (score 0):

or you can try...

```
const int size =100;  
T* array[size] = {nullptr};
T **ptr = array;
```